# Emojione area causes problem executing hidden textarea events

Tags: javascript, html, emojione

I'm using [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) inside my application. Since this plugin hides original `textarea` and uses `div` instead to show and load emojis, it causes problems in executing events like `onkeyup` and `onkeypress`. Here is my code:

```
<textarea id="Message" class="form-control" cols="80" rows="7" onchange="SMSCounter(this, event, in_array([], "Source"))" onblur="RefineCounter(this, in_array([], "Source"))" onkeypress="SetChar(event)" onkeyup="SMSCounter(this, event, in_array([], "Source"))" maxlength="765" style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float: right; display: none;" name="data[Message]" data-rel="tmplButton-solh0ecqbs"></textarea>
```

Comment: use events provided by the library https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the events in options for your area like this:

```
$("selector").emojioneArea({
  events: {
    keyup: function (editor, event) {
     console.log('event:keyup');
    },
    keydown: function (editor, event) {
      console.log('event:keydown');
    }
  }
)
```